# Using ML algorithms like decision trees, support vector machines, neural networks for panel data

Tags: time-series, logistic, neural-networks, cross-section

Someone has already asked [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/159713/time-series-cross-sectional-classification-problem) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/predictive-models-for-panel-data) on this but no one has answered yet in terms of predictive modelling.

If I have a [panel dataset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panel_data) of customers, their demographics and their order amount in dollars in a day over a period of time, how would I implement ML models(Neural network or standard ML like decision tree, logistic regression), say to forecast their next  order amount or which specific item they are likely to order or whether they are going to order anything in the next week?

Goal is to create customized engagement campaigns to improve conversion/revenue.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the data set? I'm having trouble understanding what time series has to do with it.

Comment: @user2078017 This question is too vague, you need to be more specific.

Comment: Please see if the question makes sense now.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/220000/machine-learning-techniques-for-longitudinal-data/257298#257298